# Executing a SuiteScript Remotely and Programmatically

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have a dev task to run a `Saved Csv Import` task in `NetSuite` that another team owns. We need to automate the execution of this task.

I have been able to run a `Csv_Import` task via a `SuiteScript` `Script` but I am not sure how to trigger the script remotely and programmatically when needed (not via a schedule).

Is there a way to trigger a `SuiteScript` via the Rest Api? The documentation suggests that there isn't.

What would be an ideal way to trigger a `Saved Csv Import` task remotely and programmatically?

I see there is a Soap endpoint but would like to stay away from this old architecture.

Comment: You can make your own restlet to do tasks like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a RESTlet to trigger the CSV import task.  Here's the bare bones of a RESTlet that would respond to an authenticated HTTP GET request and start a CSV import using a file already in the file cabinet with a known file id and a previously saved CSV import mapping.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(['N/task'], function (task) {
    function get() {
        return task.create({
            taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT,
            fileid: 1234,
            mappingId: 2345,
        });
    }

    return {
        get,
    };
});
```